# Django Model Form Integer as Drop Down

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a simple Model form in my project as follows:

```
class InviteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invite
        fields = ['max_guests', 'rsvp_guests', 'rsvp_attendance']
```

Max Guests is just an integer and appears for the user to type in. As the value is always small (<10), I would like this to be a dropdown instead with all values 0-max.

Is there a way to overwrite an integer input as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) as

```
class InviteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    MAX_GUESTS = (
            ('0', '0'),
            ('1', '1'),
            ('2', '2'),
            ('3', '3'),
            ('4', '4'),
            ('5', '5'),
            ('6', '6'),
            ('7', '7'),
            ('8', '8'),
            ('9', '9'),
            ('10', '10'),
            )
    max_guests = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MAX_GUESTS)
    class Meta:
        model = Invite
        fields = ['max_guests', 'rsvp_guests', 'rsvp_attendance']
```

Comment: I updated following your code but strangely it still shows as a number picker. Do I need to set anything on the view that it handles is as such?

Comment: I shuffled it around so that MAX_GUESTS and max_guests are before the meta class and seems to work now

Comment: You can put `MAX_GUESTS` at any place also outside the `form` class. As per your `before the meta class` I have updated my answer.